# Undefined Array in JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble with the following piece of code:

[I would like to be able to view the contents of `$prisonlist` in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUY5s.png)

I would like to be able to view the contents of `$prisonlist` (or `$prisonlist[some value]`) in the console, and to display it in the text of the div.
Essentially, whenever I do, it comes up with an error known as "undefined" - although my other functions that work with it seem to work just fine (such as the //

Code:

```
        $counter = 0;
                var $prisonlist=[];
                $prisonlist[0]=1;
                $('#entered').text($prisonlist[0]);
                $('#s1').click(function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass('on off');
                    $counter = $counter + 1;
                    $('#clicks').text($counter);
                    $prisn = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
                    $('#prisoners').text($prisn);
                    $boo=$prisonlist.indexOf($prisn)  //finds in array whether there is any

                    if ($boo==-1){
                    $prisonlist.push($prisn); // lists the individual inside
                        }

                });
```

Comment: Are you trying to access `$prisonlist` ouside of its scope?

Comment: I'm guessing by this you mean beyond its maximum array length - and no, it won't show anything if I try to access `$prisonlist[0]` which is defined there. It will display in the text if I make it change the text, but I can't view the full array when various values have been pushed into it.

Comment: I think @hatchet is actually asking what scope the `var $prisonlist` is defined in.  Is it local to a function, is it in a loop or is it in the global scope?

Comment: It is within $(document).ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `var $prisonlist=[];`is scoped, therefore unavailable in the console where you can see only global stuff. The solutions are:

- Quick yet ugly - declare `$prisonlist=[];` (without the `var`) in the global scope.
- My preferred - wherever you want to inspect the variable insert `console.log($prisonlist)`. This will log the current value of the variable to the console.
- Use a debugger

Comment: I only did it now because stack overflow made me wait

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, you are trying to use an array ($prisonlist) as an argument to the jquery text() function which only takes a string, number, boolean or function (but not an array).

You need to cast the array to a string first using JSON.stringify:

```
$('#element).text(JSON.stringify($prisonlist));
```

Ensure that #element isnt an input or textarea element since text() doesn't work on those (use val() instead).